# No Wifi in new Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation on Lenovo y50-70

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I'm having trouble connecting to my WiFi Network on my Lenovo y50-70 LapTop on Ubuntu 16.04.
I had it run on Windows for the first couple months, so I am positive, that it does have WiFi capabilities.
I didn't have any such problems on my old Lenovo LapTop on Ubuntu 14.04 however.
I just installed the OS, but couldn't install updates or set the clock with that. Now it doesn't show any wlan connection at the menu on the top right.
It does show a wired Ethernet connection however, when I go Edit Connections.

I tried:

-`rfkill list all & sudo rfkill unblock all` which seemed to remove a softblock on my wlan

-I can't install the proprietary BCM drivers since I don't have an Ethernet port.

-`ifconfig wlan0 & ifconfig wlan0 up` -> `wlan0: error fetching information: Device not found & wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device`

-iwconfig

```
lo  no wireless extensions.
enp9s0 no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think I've added paragraphs at the appropriate places and started with Hey everyone, which seems to have gone.

Comment: lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

Comment: 08.00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)

Comment: Subsystem: Lenovo BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0623] Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge Kernel modules: bcma